# Wrong Answer while solving differential equation in C

Tags: c, math

I am new to C programming and am writing a program to solve simple differential equations which gives output as the value of x. But I'm not getting the correct result.

I am getting the correct value of the equation, but the value of the differential equation is wrong. The code compiles without any warnings or errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

float poly(float a[], int, float);
float deriv(float a[], int, float);

int main()
{
  float x, a[10], y1, dy1;
  int deg, i;

printf("Enter the degree of polynomial equation: ");
scanf("%d", &deg);

printf("Ehter the value of x for which the equation is to be evaluated: ");
scanf("%f", &x);

for(i=0;i<=deg;i++)
{
    printf("Enter the coefficient of x to the power %d: ",i);
    scanf("%f",&a[i]);
}

y1 = poly(a, deg, x);
dy1 = deriv(a, deg, x);

printf("The value of polynomial equation for the value of x = %.2f is: %.2f",x,y1);
printf("\nThe value of the derivative of the polynomial equation at x = %.2f is: %.2f",x,dy1);

return 0;
 }

 /* function for finding the value of polynomial at some value of x */

 float poly(float a[], int deg, float x)
 {
    float p;
    int i;

p = a[deg];

for(i=deg;i>=1;i--)
{
    p = (a[i-1] + x*p);
}

return p;
}

/* function for finding the derivative at some value of x */
  float deriv(float a[], int deg, float x)
   {
   float d[10], pd = 0, ps;
int i;

for(i=0;i<=deg;i++)
{
    ps = pow(x, deg-(i+1));
    d[i] = (deg-1)*a[deg-1]*ps;
    pd = pd + d[i];
}

return pd;
}
```

Comment: General notes: Use `double` instead of `float` where any kind of accuracy is needed. An array on access is converted to a pointer ([C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)) so simply using, e.g. `float poly(float *a, int, float);` is fine (both are correct, but when using `[]` it implies the user knows 6.3.2.1). Do not include `conio.h`, it is 100% non-portable to anything other than DOS/windows. Use `stdio.h` functions instead.

Comment: Your problem is a typo.   The assignment to `d[i] = (deg-1)*a[deg-1]*ps` is using the digit `1` when it should be using the letter `i`.   Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: Two upvotes for a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a simple logical error. In the function `float deriv(float a[], int deg, float x)` It should be  `d[i] = (deg-i)*a[deg-i]*ps;`. So your function would look something like this

```
/* function for finding the derivative at some value of x */
float deriv(float a[], int deg, float x)
{
  float d[10], pd = 0, ps;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<=deg;i++)
  {
     ps = pow(x, deg-(i+1));
     d[i] = (deg-i)*a[deg-i]*ps;
     pd = pd + d[i];
  }

  return pd;
 }
```

Good luck for the future.